# How do I only allow users who are of a certain age to join?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm writing an application where users have to be at least 13 years old to join. My setup is [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) and [Unicorn server](https://github.com/defunkt/unicorn), and this is my `User` model:

**User.rb**

```
  attr_accessible :birthday

  validates_presence_of :birthday

  validate :is_certain_age

  private

  def is_certain_age
    if self.birthday
      errors.add(:base, 'You need to be at least 13.') if self.birthday > Date.today.year - 13
    end
  end
```

I've tried to test this in the browser but when I submit the registration form, it POST and remains not creating the user or not creating it. I have no clue what's going on since the unicorn server won't tell me the parameters like WEBrick would.  This is all I get:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Jun/2013 11:21:12] "POST /users HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.3460
```

My Rspec test for users show these for failures:

```
 User 
   Failure/Error: it { should be_valid }
   NoMethodError:
   undefined method `to_datetime' for 2000:Fixnum
```

*Note: using [Shoulda Matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers)*

```
User valid user age 
   Failure/Error: it { should ensure_inclusion_of(:birthday).in_range(13..150) }
   Did not expect errors to include "is not included in the list"..... 
   ...when birthday is set to 12, got error:
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'll want is:

```
errors.add(:base, 'You need to be at least 13.') if self.birthday > Date.today - 13.years
```

You were comparing a `DateTime` (`self.birthday`) to a `FixNum` (`2000`, the result of `Date.today.year - 13`), whereas in my code above: `Date.today - 13.years`, the result is a DateTime also.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up changing my validation to be this instead: `validates_inclusion_of :birthday, :in => Date.new(1900)..Time.now.years_ago(13).to_date, :message => 'Sorry, you must be at least 13 years old to join'`. Thanks for the clarification.